# inline/embedded Image attachment is not visible in mail send by PHP Swift Mailer

Tags: php, email, email-attachments, swiftmailer

I'm sending an image with an attachment that has to shown as inline image.

I can't find out what's wrong with it. I don't remember this being an issue when I coded the mailer

This is the header of of the image inside the email

```
--_=_swift_1561449240_8047151997d755eb732462545a29a594_=_
Content-Type: image/png; name=logo.png
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
X-Attachment-Id: logo
Content-ID: <logo>
Content-Disposition: inline; filename=logo.png
```

This is the function that sends an email with attachments

```
public function send(MailInterface $mail, array $attachments = array())
    {
        /* @var SwiftMail $swiftMail */
        $swiftMail = new SwiftMail(
            $mail->getSubject(),
            $mail->getBody(),
            "text/html"
        );

        foreach ($attachments as $contentId => $contentPath) {
            if (null != $contentPath) {

                // prepare content to be send as an attachment
                $attachment = SwiftAttachment::fromPath($contentPath);
                $attachment->setDisposition("inline");
                $attachment->getHeaders()->addTextHeader("Content-ID", "<" . $contentId . ">");
                $attachment->getHeaders()->addTextHeader("X-Attachment-Id", $contentId);

                // add the attachment to the mail
                $swiftMail->embed($attachment);
            }
        }

    /* ... etc ... */
```

In the template I'm setting the source to the content ID like this:

```
<img src="cid:<logo>">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to show the image in the email as inline, use Swift_Image

```
$cid = $mail->embed(\Swift_Image::fromPath('/path/to/image'));
$emailView->assign('cid', $cid);
```

And at the Template:

```
<img src="{cid}" />
```

But be careful:
It does not work with coincident $mail->attach(). I don´t know why yet.